# Is it possible to set a CSSTransitionGroup on a table cell in ReactJS?

Tags: css, css-transitions, reactjs

Consider this JSX structure:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{this.props.firstName}</td>
      <td>{this.props.lastName}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

I would like to use a [CSSTransitionGroup](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html) to set the background color of a td when one of the props is updated, like so:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
        <td key={this.props.firstName}>{this.props.firstName}</td>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      <td>{this.props.lastName}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

The problem here is that the ReactCSSTransitionGroup renders as a span, which is not a valid child of a table row.  So is it possible with React to set enter/leave animations on table cells?

Answer (score 7):

React CSS Transitions can be specified to use a different container element than span if you wish by using the `component` property.

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#rendering-a-different-component

If that doesn't work I'd recommend not using a table and using divs instead, perhaps with display: table / table-row / table-cell.

Comment: I just removed the wrapping <tbody> and it appears to work fine (yes, it was wacky in firefox prior).

   </tr>
     </thead>
       <ReactCSSTransitionGroup component="tbody" transitionName="shipping">
     {rows}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
   </table>

Comment: Have the same problem in firefox now.. when i disable background color in firebug and enable it again, it works... hm.. did you find a solution?